# Delete cookie once paypal payment is completed using IPN

Tags: php, cookies, paypal

I am creating a payment system which is almost done, the only left bit is removing all the cookies used for transactions.

Now I can remove all cookies if I add a remove function to one of my website page and set it to refresh, that does work but however that require the user to go back to that page to begin with, some user may once use the paypal to make a payment close the browser, so next time they open the webpage the cookies would still be valid.

Im trying to delete the cookies in the IPN file where paypal uses it to communicate with the web page, but I cant seem to delete it as I cant get the page to refresh, is there another way of deleting the cookies?

PHP

```
foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $value){
    setcookie( $key, $value, time()-(100000 * 60), '/' );
}
if(count($_COOKIE) !=0){
    // I also tried this method, refreshing the IPN file but it didnt work.
    header("Refresh:0");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is wrong. You should keep track of the transaction in your database, not in cookies. Cookies can be used for sessions.

Then you can, once you receive the payment confirmation from PayPal, over your IPN page, close the transactions in your database.

In other words, the IPN page is called by PayPal, never sees the customers browser, and therefore cannot delete the cookies there.

Comment: hmm I understand, the cookies I have had nothing to do with the database though, it only has information of how many items has the customer chosen to buy, and price. Those information will not be stored to the database.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but unless you secure your cookies the customer can alter the price of your products, do you want that? So either store the transactions in the session, and send the session id to paypal, so you receive it back on the IPN page and manipulate the session, or use a database. The latter is the preferred method.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I knew the customer can alter the price, I do have a function that checkes the price from the cookies with the one from the database once IPN is called. I guess I will have to delete the cookies once paypal redirect the user to my webpage, I just find it annoying because if the customer decides to close the browser before redirecting, next time they open the webpage the cookies would still be there. Even if i re programme the code to have the price connected directed to the database, I would still like to have a cookie for total number of items chosen by users.

Comment: Believe me, I have been there, using cookies this way is a bad idea. You've now come across two reasons: Price manipulation, and clearing transactions. There will be more. Choose the correct method and all these problems will disappear.

Comment: could you elaborate more? please so i can try to use a new method. Also, I see alot of website that once you choose your item whether you are logged in or not, if you close and open the browser again the item would still be there, wouldnt that require cookies?

Comment: Yes, it could be done with a cookie, but we normally refer to persistent data as a 'session'. PHP supports sessions: http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php You could start by storing the transactions in a session variable. Then you give PayPal the session id and you can use that on the IPN page to clear the transations. No database needed (although that would be better, it allows you to check incomplete orders, for instance).

Comment: Thanks I will have a look :)

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP manual comments section for `setcookie()`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#109173

Want to remove a cookie?

Many people do it the complicated way:
setcookie('name', 'content', time()-3600);

But why do you make it so complicated and risk it not working, when the client's time is wrong? Why fiddle around with time();

Here's the easiest way to unset a cookie:
setcookie('name', 'content', 1);

Thats it.

Comment: The OP asks how to avoid the redirect, not how to remove a cookie.

Comment: I know this method, the way I am removing the cookie does work, whether is less efficient or not, it doesnt matter now. What I want to know is how I can get this function to work without having to refresh the page, because the IPN file does not refresh.